# How to remove repeated samples from a time series in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, duplicates

Currently I'm working with time series data in Pandas. The series are the 3D positions of several markers, so my Dataframe looks as follows:

[A.x, A.y, A.z, B.x, B.y, B.z, C.x, C.y, C.z ... etc.]

Now sometimes the system lost track of one the markers, so the position stays the same over several frames. I want to set these values to NaN (to later interpolate them), but I can't figure out how to do this. So:

```
 A.x  A.y  A.z      A.x  A.y  A.z
[0.1, 0.2, 0.2]    [0.1, 0.2, 0.2]
[0.1, 0.2, 0.2]    [NaN, NaN, NaN]
[0.1, 0.2, 0.2] -> [NaN, NaN, NaN]
[0.3, 0.2, 0.2]    [0.3, 0.2, 0.2] <- Kept because at least one position was different
[0.2, 0.2, 0.2]    [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
[0.3, 0.2, 0.2]    [0.1, 0.2, 0.2] <- Kept as it was not the same as the immediately preceding frame
```

Dropping duplicated doesn't work, as it does not look for "repeated" values but duplicates in general. I think a solution looking at 3 columns (so 1 point) at the same time would be the best?

Comment: IMHO, `[A.x, A.y, A.z, B.x, B.y, B.z, C.x, C.y, C.z ... etc.]` doesn't look like a dataframe, it looks like an array to me.

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity, I meant that would be a single "row" from the data frame. Updated the example to make it a bit clearer

Comment: Make two dataframes one less at the head one less at the tail - compare and use that as filter to set Nan. I'll put an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple version below.

Generic Version:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2], 
        [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
    ],
    columns="A.x A.y A.z B.x B.y B.z".split(),
)
#    A.x  A.y  A.z  B.x  B.y  B.z
# 0  0.1  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.2  0.2
# 1  0.1  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.2  0.2
# 2  0.1  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2
# 3  0.3  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.2  0.2
# 4  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.1  0.2  0.2
# 5  0.3  0.2  0.2  0.1  0.2  0.2
# 6  0.3  0.2  0.2  0.1  0.2  0.2

# identify repeating data
diff = (df.values[:-1]  == df.values[1:])
# [[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#  [ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
#  [False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
#  [False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
#  [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#  [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]

allfalse = np.full((1, diff.shape[1]), False)
# [[False, False, False, False, False, False]]

# add allfalse as first row
diff2 = np.concatenate((allfalse, diff), axis=0)

# grouped into 3s
grouped = diff2.reshape(diff2.shape[0], diff2.shape[1] // 3, 3)

# [[[False, False, False], [False, False, False]],
#  [[ True,  True,  True], [ True,  True,  True]],
#  [[ True,  True,  True], [False,  True,  True]],
#  [[False,  True,  True], [False,  True,  True]],
#  [[False,  True,  True], [False,  True,  True]],
#  [[False,  True,  True], [ True,  True,  True]],
#  [[ True,  True,  True], [ True,  True,  True]]]

# mask for triplets
mask = np.all(grouped, axis=2)
# [[False, False],
#  [ True,  True],
#  [ True, False],
#  [False, False],
#  [False, False],
#  [False,  True],
#  [ True,  True]]

grouped[~mask] = False
# [[[False, False, False], [False, False, False]],
#  [[ True,  True,  True], [ True,  True,  True]],
#  [[ True,  True,  True], [False, False, False]],
#  [[False, False, False], [False, False, False]],
#  [[False, False, False], [False, False, False]],
#  [[False, False, False], [ True,  True,  True]],
#  [[ True,  True,  True], [ True,  True,  True]]]

# finally reshape back into original shape
repeated = grouped.reshape(diff2.shape[0], diff2.shape[1])
# [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
#  [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#  [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
#  [False, False, False, False, False, False],
#  [False, False, False, False, False, False],
#  [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
#  [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]]

# set repeating values to NAN
df.values[repeated] = np.nan
#    A.x  A.y  A.z  B.x  B.y  B.z
# 0  0.1  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.2  0.2
# 1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 2  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.2  0.2  0.2
# 3  0.3  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.2  0.2
# 4  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.1  0.2  0.2
# 5  0.3  0.2  0.2  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Simple(r) Version:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.3, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.3, 0.2, 0.2],
        [0.3, 0.2, 0.2],
    ],
    columns="A.x  A.y  A.z".split(),
)

#    A.x  A.y  A.z
# 0  0.1  0.2  0.2
# 1  0.1  0.2  0.2
# 2  0.1  0.2  0.2
# 3  0.3  0.2  0.2
# 4  0.2  0.2  0.2
# 5  0.3  0.2  0.2
# 6  0.3  0.2  0.2


# difference between consecutive values
diff = (df.values[:-1]  == df.values[1:])

# [[ True,  True,  True],
#  [ True,  True,  True],
#  [False,  True,  True],
#  [False,  True,  True],
#  [False,  True,  True],
#  [ True,  True,  True]]

# collapse rows into single value np.all(..., axis=1)
# make array len == number of rows in original DF
repeated = np.insert(np.all(diff, axis=1), 0, False)
# [False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True]

# modify df in-place
df.values[repeated] = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]

#    A.x  A.y  A.z
# 0  0.1  0.2  0.2
# 1  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 2  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 3  0.3  0.2  0.2
# 4  0.2  0.2  0.2
# 5  0.3  0.2  0.2
# 6  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I'm certain this can be done prettier and more efficient, but this is step 2 :)

I'll think about B.x... C.x part... will post update.

Enjoy!